# How to host VB ASP.NET webapp from a VB windows form application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, winforms, web-applications, lan

I'm developing a windows form application which I want to host webapp to the LAN when the application first loads.  From there I want to also have a database accessible over the same LAN connection so that I can post information and communicate between the 2 vb applications.

My question is how you think I would best host the web application from vb.  Obviously I need to identify the network parameters so that I can find a port etc, but how should I go about hosting the webapp?
I only need it to go to the LAN and not to rest of the world.
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean [something like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/self-host-a-web-api) ?

Comment: @Crowcoder, Yes thank you so much.  All I needed was to know that its called Self Hosting